# Almost there installing Django/Python/PyISAPIe/IIS7, but message "Possible recursion detected" - configuration question

Tags: python, django, iis-7, pyisapie

I'm installing Django onto a Windows system with Python 2.6 and IIS7 using PyISAPIe, and I'm so close I can taste it.  Creating a little Django project and running it gives me:

> Possible recursion detected! You probably did a passthrough with PyISAPIe configured as an application map instead of a wildcard map.

From various other postings, I get the impression it has to do with the handler mappings in IIS, and specifically how PyISAPIe is mapped to handle calls, but I'm at a loss beyond that point.  One blog suggests changing PyIsapie.py to reflect a different error, but that just shifts the reaction around, not corrects the problem.  In IIS7 PyISAPIe is set to * (complete wildcard) mapped to the .dll.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The question is kinda old but since I also ran into this prob and just solved it, maybe for future references I should mention that for the PyISAPIe script mapping someone must do the following in the properties of his virtual directory(home directory->configuration):

#### 1) Add application extension

```
- executable:browse the `PyISAPIe.dll`, extension: `.py`
```

#### 2) Insert wildcard application maps

```
- browse the `PyISAPIe.dll` (untick: Verify that file exists)
```

Hope it helps!